# set cursor to block

Tags: cursor

I am trying to set the cursor as a block/box that surrounds the current character as opposed to a line cursor:

This is my default that I got pressing `:set guicursor=<Tab>`

```
:set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor/lCursor,ve:ver35-Cursor,o:hor50-Cursor,i-ci:ver25-Cursor/lCursor,r-cr:hor20-Cursor/lCurso
r,sm:block-Cursor-blinkwait175-blinkoff150-blinkon175
```

I tried changing lCursor to bCursor or cursor, like so:

```
:set guicursor=n-v-c:block...
```

And also

```
:set guicursor=n-c-v:block-nCursor
```

but that's not the away apparently.

I need this because the way it indicates characters at the moment doesn't reflect the white spaces in a way i understand them.

---

PD: I just realized that way you set it for `gVim` but I am not using gVim, and can't find much for vim.

Help please : - ) !!

Answer (score 4):

- For standard **Vi/Vim** I changed Alacritty's (terminal emulator) cursor mode from Beam to Block, and Vim takes that.
- For **gVim** type `:help guicursor`

Or type `:set guicursor=` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete with the default value. In my case it looks like this:

```
:set guicursor=n-v-c:block-nCursor/lCursor,ve:ver35-Curs
or,o:hor50-Cursor,i-ci:ver25-Cursor/lCursor,r-cr:hor20-
Cursor/lCursor,sm:block-Cursor-blinkwait175-blinkoff150
-blinkon175
```

As you may infer the syntax is a comma separated list of `<modes>:<options>`.

And both modes and options can be a list of values, in this case separated by dashes `-`.

The first one is for normal,visual or command mode, uses a block Cursor.

So this `n-v-c:block-nCursor` is valid for normal, visual and command line mode, and uses the block cursor with an option nCursor which is a highlight group (no idea what this is).

Then there is a `/lCursor` which is an optional highlight group.

If instead of block we use `ver{N}` or `hor{N}` we convert the cursor to a line, horizontal or vertical, of a specific width.

That's more or less the idea.

Comment: Can you add to your answer the content from the page you link? This is useful in case the page you link disappears one day and it's also more convenient for future readers who will have an answer directly rather than having to search another website.

Comment: Yes, I will. @statox

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much better like this :)